# Get custom field values of taxonomy terms

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I added a Custom Field named 'cognome_nome' in my Custom Taxonomy named 'authors'. 
I would like to display in a Archive Page a list of all 'cognome_nome' values of the terms.

Examples:

1.term

- Name: Elena P
- slug: elena_p
- cognome_nome: P Elena

2.term

- Name: Andrea P
- slug: andrea_p
- cognome_nome: P Andrea

I would like to display:

- P Elena
- P Andrea

and so on... Do you think it's possible?

Thank you in advance :)

EDIT

I'm using this code to list all the terms:

```
$terms = get_terms( 'authors' );
 if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
     echo '<ul>';
     foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
       echo '<li> <a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';

     }
     echo '</ul>';
 }
```

Comment: Hi Elena. Yes it is possible, but could you please provide more details on what you've tried already (and why it didn't work)?

Comment: To be honest I don't know where to begin :( I have a simple code to display all the terms Name. I insert that code above.. @kraftner

Comment: Does `$term->cognome_nome` not work?

Comment: unfortunately doesn't work :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you using Advanced Custom Fields plugin? If you are, try this if it works:

```
foreach ($terms as $term) {
     // $cognome_nome will be "P Elena" or "P Andrea" in your case
     $cognome_nome = get_field('cognome_nome', $term->taxonomy.'_'.$term->term_id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Nam! Do you even know how can I order the list alphabetically? For example I have: A Daniel, P Andrea, P Elena, Z Carl.

I tried the `orderby => name` but it doesn't work..

Comment: It should work, you still use get_terms('authors') to get the terms right?

Comment: Thanks alot, I was searching for the solution for the last 4 hrs and lost all the hopes, then found this answer.
Thanks